# sqlalchemy update part of date

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with `Date` and I need to set only `day` and `month` part of date to `1` and keep the original year for a set of ids.

So I was trying to form expression like (and variations of it):

```
session.query(
    UserData
).filter(
    UserData.id.in_(selected_ids)
).update(
    {
        'user_date': cast((func.date_part('year', UserData.user_date), 1, 1), Date),
    },
    synchronize_session='fetch',
)
```

I'm simply unable to get it right.
Help?

Comment: Instead of `date_part` use `date_trunc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some more struggle I came up with this:

```
session.query(
    UserData
).filter(
    UserData.id.in_(selected_ids)
).update(
    {
        'user_date': cast(func.concat(extract('year', UserData.user_date, type_=Date), '-01-01'), Date),
    },
    synchronize_session='fetch',
)
```

`extract` was failing until I coerced the data type, then I created new date string and cast it back to `Date`.

There was another occurrence where field was also `Date` but returned data type was string (format `2000-05-21`), so this solution was failing. So I solved it like a normal `string` with taking first 4 digits of a year with `func.substr(UserData.user_date, 1, 4)`:

```
session.query(
    UserData
).filter(
    UserData.id.in_(selected_ids)
).update(
    {
         'user_date': func.concat(func.substr(UserData.user_date, 1, 4), '-01-01')),
    },
    synchronize_session='fetch',
)
```